# Passing Parameters to a PowerShell Script in MDT 2013

Tags: powershell, mdt

I have a PowerShell script that takes an array as an input parameter:

```
Param( 
    Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [System.String[]] $Adapters
)
Write-Output "Disabling network adapter(s)."
foreach ($adapter in $Adapters) {
    Disable-NetAdapterBinding -Name $adapter -ComponentID ms_tcpip6  
    Write-Host $adapter
}
```

I get the following error when I call the function from an MDT 2013 task sequence:

```
+ ..."E:\Deploy\Scripts\Disable-IPV6.ps1" -Adapters @(Teamed_NIC1, Teamed_...
    Missing argument in parameter list.
```

This is what my call to the function in MDT 2013 looks like:

[image: PowerShell script: <code>%SCRIPTROOT%\Disable-IPV6.ps1</code>; Parameters: <code>-Adapters @("Teamed_NIC1", "Teamed_NIC2")</code>]

I suspect that MDT is handling the quotation marks in an unexpected way.

Comment: In the parameters block, try calling like this -->

`-Adapters "Teamed_NIC1" "Teamed_NIC2"`

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh That would invoke the script with one named parameter (`-Adapters "Teamed_NIC1"`) and one unnamed parameter (`"Teamed_NIC2"`).

Comment: Yes @AnsgarWiechers - I realize that now, looking at your answer. Thank you for pointing that out and educating us folks. :)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Good clarification. The key part I needed was _is only recognized within PowerShell_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@("Teamed_NIC1","Teamed_NIC2")` is a PowerShell array. That construct is only recognized *within* PowerShell, but not by the environment from which you invoke the PowerShell script. The same applies if you remove the `@()`.

You cannot really pass array values to a parameter when invoking a PowerShell script from outside PowerShell. A common workaround is to pass the argument as a delimited string and split it:

```
Param(
    Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$Adapters
)
$AdapterList = $Adapters -split ','
foreach ($adapter in $AdapterList) {
    ...
}
```

with an invocation like this:

```
%SCRIPTROOT%\Disable-IPV6.ps1 "Teamed_NIC1,Teamed_NIC2"
```

Or you can drop the parameter definition and use the [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-3.0) `$args`:

```
if (-not $args) { throw 'Missing argument.' }

foreach ($adapter in $args) {
    ...
}
```

with an invocation like this:

```
%SCRIPTROOT%\Disable-IPV6.ps1 "Teamed_NIC1" "Teamed_NIC2"
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it'd be something simple like this.